# What happens when branched branch gets merged

Tags: git, github

I have a question for which I couldn't find an answer in Git Pro book.

Suppose I created `branchA` off `master`, did some changes, commited and pushed for pull request.
I'm pretty sure that this branch will get merged to `origin/master` at some point but I want to create `branchB` off `branchA` for further development based on submitted change.

Question is what happens with `branchB` when `branchA` will get merged?

My take is that if pull request approver merges `branchA` then my `branchB` pull request will already contain commits from `branchA` and diff will effectively show only changes between `branchA` and `branchB`

However if it's not yet merged, pull request for `branchB` will show changes from both branches and it's up to approver to either merge `branchA` and then `branchB` or only `branchB`.

Please correct my reasoning

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.  To answer your question, nothing happens to `branchB` when `branchA` gets merged, only the diff would change to `master`.

Comment: ... "or only branchB", which if merged before branchA would effectively merge branchA changes as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You had this situation:

```
                       branch-A
                          v
              1---2---3---4
             /
O---O---O---O
            ^
          master
```

Then you did this:

```
                       branch-A       branch-B
                          v               v
              1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8
             /
O---O---O---O
            ^
          master
```

To summarize the current state:

- A pull request for A to master will show the difference between A and master, which is effectively commits 1-4
- A pull request for B to master will show the difference between B and master, which is effectively commits 1-8, and thus includes all changes from A, that has not yet been merged into master

If you now decide to complete the pull request for A, you have this scenario:

```
                       branch-A       branch-B
                          v               v
              1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8
             /             \
O---O---O---O---------------X
                            ^
                          master
```

Where X is now the merge commit. After this, with no other changes or operations, if you revisit the pull request for B it should now (again, still) show the difference between B and master, but now it only includes commits 5-8.

If instead you had completed pull request for B first, you had ended up with this:

```
                       branch-A       branch-B
                          v               v
              1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8
             /                             \
O---O---O---O-------------------------------Y
                                            ^
                                          master
```

If you now revisit the pull request for A, depending on the tool you would either see an empty diff, or the pull request can be marked as completed (I seem to recall Bitbucket for Enterprise uses this approach), as all changes in A have already been merged successfully.

So to summarize:

**TL;DR**: Your B-branch is not really affected, but the diff between it and master will initially include all changes from A as well, but after completing PR for A, it will only show diff between B and master, and no longer show the changes from A as they have already been merged. Your paragraph about "My take" is thus spot on.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to understand is that pull requests are not at all a Git feature. They are something that certain Git hosting sites do, and they do it in different ways.

Let's confine our considerations to GitHub. GitHub handles this situation in a very convenient and coherent way.

For purposes of the example, let's say you have a branch `branchA` and you submit it to GitHub as a pull request to be merged into `main`. You then make a new branch `branchB` off the end of `branchA` and you continue development there. This happens to me a lot, so I have pretty deep experience of how it works.

There are two possible ideal subsequent outcomes:

### Ideal path 1

The first ideal thing that might happen is that while you are still working on `branchB`, the PR for `branchA` is accepted and merged. Then you simply rebase `branchB` onto `main`, like this:

```
git rebase --onto main branchA branchB
```

That incantation rips the `branchB` commits off the point where `branchB` diverged from `branchA` and tacks them on to the end of `main`. You continue working until you are ready to submit the PR, and you submit it to be merged into `main`. Since `branchB` now comes directly off `main`, the PR will consist only of the commits that you've made on `branchB`, which is just what you want.

Observe that this works just fine *even if more commits were added to `branchA`* as part of its acceptance.

### Ideal path 2

Now let's say that, instead, you finish your `branchB` work while the `branchA` PR has not yet been accepted. No problem; go ahead and submit the PR for `branchB` to GitHub, but when you do, as you construct the new PR in the GitHub web interface, tell GitHub that *you want to merge `branchB` into `branchA`* (not into `main`). By doing that, two wonderful things happen:

- The PR for `branchB` consists only of the commits you made on `branchB`, which is just what you want.
- If the `branchA` PR is now accepted and merged, GitHub *magically changes the `branchB` PR* so that it is now asking to merge into `main`! Moreover, the PR *still* consists only of the commits you made on `branchB`!

  That, too, works just fine even if `branchA` acquired some more commits as part of its acceptance. In that case, however, after `branchA` PR is accepted and merged, you might want to merge `main` into `branchB` ("reverse merge") just to pick up (and perhaps reconcile) the latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

> My take is that if pull request approver merges branchA then my
>   branchB pull request will already contain commits from branchA and
>   diff will effectively show only changes between branchA and branchB

It depends how you setup the Pull Request for BranchB. If you select to merge it into `master` and BranchA is not yet merged you will see all changes. But you can also create the Pull Request saying merge BranchB into BranchA then you only see the changes from BranchB to BranchA.

You can always change to which branch a branch will be merged. So assume first you setup Pull Request to merge BranchB into BranchA to see only that diff. If BranchA gets merged to master you can either rebase BranchB or merge master into BranchB.

Answer (score 0):

> Based on Lasse's answer, if changes are merged into A after B is created, and then A is merged into B again, before A is merged into `master`, then everything will work as expected and shown in his answer. Is this correct?

Not exactly: no change is "merged into A".

A is pushed for PR, meaning to request changes *from* A to be merged *to* `master`.

What [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57392824) suggests is B is not affected by that.

If B were to be pushed for its own PR (request to merge B changes to `master`), you would see changes from A *and* B initially.

But once A has been merged to `master`, the PR for B would be automatically updated, and would reflect only B changes (to be merged to `master`), and no longer A changes (*already* merged to `master`, since its own PR has been completed).