# Should I branch from a branch when waiting on reviewer to merge a pull request?

Tags: git

So, I created a pull request in my `ticket-3` branch and my reviewer reviewed and found one minor thing for me to change. I've made this change, pushed the commit, and now just waiting for the reviewer to approve the merge request. I'm confident that no other changes are to be made for the pull request and would like to work on a feature in my app.

What is the best way to go about this? Should I create another branch from my `ticket-3` branch? If I do this, what happens to the new branch once the `ticket-3` branch has merged with the `main` branch?

I'm sure there is a common practice for this, however I haven't had a dev job yet so not sure what it could be. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392328/what-happens-when-branched-branch-gets-merged), but the answer doesn't appear to be a branched branch...

Thanks and appreciate the help.

Comment: There shouldn't be too much of a problem in branching off the current `ticket-3`.

Comment: ok. So after the merge, the new branch I created would just be a branch off the `main` branch?

Comment: No, it will be a branch off `ticket-3`, _but_ functionally speaking, there shouldn't be any conflicts with `main`, other than the new work which you added since branching.

Comment: Gotcha. So, if I eventually wanted the new branch to be merged with the main branch, I would merge it into `ticket-3` then into the `main` branch?

Comment: Thanks for the help, just trying to wrap my head around this

Comment: Worth mentioning: you don't really branch from a branch. You branch from a commit. When you start a new branch using some existing branch's name, you're really telling Git: *resolve the existing branch's name to a commit hash ID, then make a new branch name using that hash ID.* Later changes to the "source" branch don't affect the new branch at all, because branch names never have any relationships to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make a branch from `ticket-3`, while `ticket-3` is merged (non-fast-forward) with `main`, you will have to rebase it on top of `main` eventually.

```
 m--m--m--m--m---M    (main)
     \          /
      3--3--3--3      (ticket-3)
                \
                 4--4 (ticket-4)

 git rebase --onto main ticket-3 ticket-4

 m--m--m--m--m---M         (main)
     \          / \
      3--3--3--3   4'--4'  (ticket-4)
               | 
           (ticket-3)
```

If `ticket-3` is merged in a fast-forward manner, you don't have anything to do.

```
 m--m--3--3--3--3      (main, ticket-3)
                 \
                  4--4 (ticket-4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not start on a ticket that depends upon a pending pull request. This can cause serious complications, especially if the pull request is rejected or greatly altered. Feature branches need to be independent. If the dependency is so tight that you cannot proceed without the earlier pull request, this should be part of that pull request (one pull request can satisfy multiple tickets).

Comment: In the context of the OP, the PR won't be rejected/altered, hence my answer.

Comment: @VonC your answer is delightful but it's an opinion based question so I gave my opinion. This is a beginner who has already proven not to know what pulling is. Bad work habits should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

I handle this issue the same way I handle the issue that others may work on master while I am doing work on a dev branch.

checkout and pull master to get up-to-date master

create dev1 branch and work on dev1 branch.

Before pushing dev1, merge the current top of master into dev1

(checkout and pull master. checkout dev1. "git merge master" to merge master changes into dev1)

Push dev1 and make a pull request.

Got more work to do? Check out master and create dev2 branch from master.
During this period my dev1 gets merged into master. So now go get the top of master as described above, and merge my dev1 changes from master into dev2, just as described above.

Note: This depends on dev2 not requiring the changes in dev1.

As noted in other answers, if dev2 requires dev1 and dev1 is not merged, it can be handled, but gets more complicated and the best answer depends on the situation.

Comment: I'm kind of repeating the answer from Matt, but with some specific details on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to create feature branches independently of one another based on your Jira ticket number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).