# Git - Working with dependent branches in PR based workflow

Tags: git, git-branch, pull-request

I am working in a PR based workflow and here is the situation created

Two branches were created from `master`

```
1. branchA library changes, with its own ongoing PR
2. branchB app depending on library, with its own ongoing PR
```

Both are two different developers.

`branchA` changes some APIs and now `branchB` has to adapt to that.

`branchB` has to take those changes from `branchA` so that they test everything works properly after the `API changes`. I am following this approach right now.

from `branchB`

```
git fetch 
git merge branchA
```

build your code and check if your changes in `branchB` is in sync with API changes from `branchA`.

**Issue 1** -
Next I push my changes to my PR, but now my PR has files from `branchA` as well along with my changes in `branchB`. This is happening because `branchA` is not yet merged to `master` and is still under its own PR review.

To avoid the above issue, I do the following -

I create a local copy of my changes outside the git folder, revert the merge with

```
git reset --hard
```

Now I bring those changes from local folder to git and then push it to PR.

**Issue 2** -
Now Because of `Continuous Integration(CI) jenkins` , both `branchA` and `branchB` PRs will fail the builds. To avoid this, I disable the `app` build on jenkins, so that `branchA` PR goes through the `CI`. And then I push `branchB` with `app` build ON.

**Question** -

1. How should both PRs be maintained due to dependency so that each has their own files for review.
2. Is our approach in handling CI correct. i.e disable the app till the library changes get in and then push the app
3. Or create `one big PR` with all the changes by merging one branch with other (`after individual PRs are reviewed`) with internal discussion and then push.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392328/what-happens-when-branched-branch-gets-merged

Comment: IMO, you are structuring the workflow incorrectly. Branches are not intended to separate areas of code that must work together (you would used folders to do that). Branches are instead used to separate changes *over time*, so that you can go back and forth between different *working* states if need be. When someone changes the library, they must *also* change the users of the library *at the same time*. Otherwise, how would they know that the library changes are sound?

Comment: @j6t, the library developer is not aware of the app, since the app itself is a huge code base and its not possible for the developer to make changes in app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe a backend/frontend workflow. In my experience the backend is done first, then the frontend. That's the easiest.

Probably you describe a situation with a tight deadline. That way the backender could prepare just an API without actual business logic and provide fake data with a proper format so the frontender could start work sooner. Another solution that the fake API is emulated purely on the frontend but that's more brittle since usually a backender knows better how the API works and what data format exactly.

But if you want your GIT workflow anyway (I'll describe the work for the frontend):

- Usually backend/frontend parts are placed into separate folders.
- Checkout the backend folder while the current branch is `branchB`:

```
git checkout branchA -- src/backend
```

Where `src/backend` - your backend folder

- The backend files are added to the index so remove them from it:

```
git reset src/backend
```

(You could use `git restore` also)

- After work on the frontend, stage any new files in the frontend:

```
git add src/frontend
```

- Commit and push into `origin/branchB`
- If you don't need the backend files, clear them:

```
git clean src/backend
```

Comment: What if both are backend branches, and one branch changes the API, that calls for a different question I guess ?

Comment: @Nitron_707 added as a separate answer not to clutter the initial one and have 2 distinct solution. you could upvote the new answer to reward my efforts

Comment: sure thing, thanks for your time and sharing of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked in the comments whats about if the both branches are backend, so we have a situation where we work on the same files in different branches!

Hmm, it got more interesting but the solution could be even paradoxically easier:

- You are on the `branchB`, prepare a patch with changes from the `branchA`, place it maybe outside the repository:

```
git diff ...branchA > ../patch
```

- Apply the patch to the current `branchB`:

```
git apply ../patch
```

- Work on your feature, you could change the same files that were changed in the `branchA`
- Rollback changes from the `branchA` by reversing the patch:

```
git apply -R ../patch
```

- Now you have only your changes, commit and push

Note this is more error-prone since you could work potentially on the same code lines...

To improve DX all these scenarios could be scripted/automated, added to git and made available to all members of the team.